# Should we combine masterdata calls into one call?

Tags: rest, angular

WE have a REST Based application with Angular 2 client, In the application we hit some master data api's like country , agreement etc all the time at login some 6-7 calls would it be good (performance aspect) to combine all these calls into one call?

Comment: Why negative votes? Whats irrelevant in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do so unless the API endpoints doesn't return some big data. But in the back end I still keep different functions to for each items.

Here is an example. For the dashboard I have to populate 3 dropdown menus (They are the filters). So I combined all 3 calls under a `/api/dashboard/filters` call. In the backend I do fetch each of these separately but using `Promise.all` to ensure concurrency. It will look like as bellow

```
  try {
    let [businessUnits, departments, filter3] = await Promise.all([
      Employee.getBusinessUnits(),
      EmployeeStatus.getDepartments(),
      Employee.getFilter3()
    ]);

    res.json({ businessUnits, departments, filter3 });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({ error: e });
  }
```

But if you use http/2, I think it is not necessary to combine these calls